# Is there any way to replace an entire array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

So, I have a problem in MongoDB... I have stored some data in MongoDB and it basically looks like:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "aa",
    importance: [0.5, 0.25, 0.25]
}
```

Where this importance attribute is an array that I will have to keep updating, e.g., after getting some data, it should be updated to [0.80, 0.10, 0.10]...

In this toy problem, I don't really understand how to replace a full array. Do I have to do it elementwise somehow? If so, it is not a tractable solution in my case, because the number of elements in my array reach above 1000.

Comment: Have you looked this [$each](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the entire `importance` array in an update by using [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set):

```js
db.test.update({_id: 1}, {$set: {importance: [0.80, 0.10, 0.10]}})
```

Comment: Thanks sooo much! I was reading the docs and still somehow missed out on $set.